# Magento 2 REST API Assigning Thumbnail Image On Configurable Products

Tags: php, rest, magento, magento2

I'm currently able to add products via the Magento 2 REST API (Magento 2.2.1) but have 1 major problem.

With Single Products everything is working great and I'm able to create them with images and assign images as thumbnails, etc. However with Configurable Products the images aren't being assigned as thumbnails, but are still successfully uploaded.

Here's a Single Product REST call which works fine:

```
{
"product": {
    "sku": "08130056-DARKNAVY",
    "name": "Dakine Campus 25L Backpack - Dark Navy",
    "price": "44.9900",
    "status": "1",
    "visibility": "4",
    "type_id": "simple",
    "weight": "1.0000",
    "extension_attributes": {
        "stock_item": {
            "manage_stock": 1,
            "qty": "1.0000",
            "is_in_stock": true
        }
    },
    "options": [],
    "tier_prices": [],
    "media_gallery_entries": [{
        "media_type": "image",
        "label": "Dakine Campus 25L Backpack - Dark Navy",
        "position": "0",
        "disabled": 0,
        "types": [],
        "file": "\/media\/catalog\/product\/i\/\/i\/m\/image_8735.jpg",
        "content": {
            "base64_encoded_data": "IMAGE BASE64 HERE",
            "type": "image\/jpeg",
            "name": "08130056 DARKNAVY"
        }
    }, {
        "media_type": "image",
        "label": "Dakine Campus 25L Backpack - Dark Navy",
        "position": "0",
        "disabled": 0,
        "types": ["image", "small_image", "thumbnail", "swatch_image"],
        "file": "\/media\/catalog\/product\/i\/\/i\/m\/image_8736.jpg",
        "content": {
            "base64_encoded_data": "IMAGE BASE64 HERE",
            "type": "image\/jpeg",
            "name": "08130056 DARKNAVY"
        }
    }],
    "attribute_set_id": 62,
    "custom_attributes": [{
        "attribute_code": "manufacturer",
        "value": "503"
    }, {
        "attribute_code": "color",
        "value": "452"
    }, {
        "attribute_code": "short_description",
        "value": "<span>The Campus 25 litre follows the lead of our popular Campus 33 litre back-to-school backpack with a slightly smaller volume-great for smaller students or smaller workloads. Packed with all the same features including a large top compartment with a padded laptop sleeve and room for books and binders, a fleece lined pocket for sunglasses, a slim organiser pocket, and a handy insulated pocket to keep lunch and snacks cool. Padded shoulder straps and an adjustable sternum strap ensure a perfect fit. Dimensions =&nbsp;<\/span>18.5 x 12 x 9\" [ 47 x 31 x 23cm ]<div><ul><li>Limited Lifetime Warranty<\/li><li>600D Polyester<\/li><li>Fits most 14\" laptops<\/li><li>Insulated cooler pocket<\/li><li>Organiser pocket<\/li><li>Fleece lined pocket for sunglasses<\/li><li>Mesh side pockets<\/li><li>Adjustable sternum strap<\/li><\/ul><\/div><br>"
    }, {
        "attribute_code": "barcode",
        "value": "610934177053"
    }, {
        "attribute_code": "category_ids",
        "value": [350]
    }, {
        "attribute_code": "meta_title",
        "value": "Dakine Campus 25L Backpack - Dark Navy"
    }, {
        "attribute_code": "meta_keyword",
        "value": "dakine,campus,25l,backpack,-,dark,navy,urbansurfer,urban,surfer,mens,backpacks"
    }, {
        "attribute_code": "meta_description",
        "value": "Dakine Campus 25L Backpack - Dark Navy - Shop online for a large range of  including Dakine with fast, free shipping from an official stockist."
    }, {
        "attribute_code": "news_from_date",
        "value": "2017-12-22 10:56:59"
    }, {
        "attribute_code": "news_to_date",
        "value": "2018-01-22 10:56:59"
    }]
},
"save_options": true
}
```

And here's a configurable product where for some reason the thumbnail, image, small_image and swatch aren't being set:

```
{
"product": {
    "sku": "226787-705-29",
    "name": "Levis Dawson Lace Up Boots - Dark Brown",
    "price": "99.9900",
    "status": "1",
    "visibility": "4",
    "type_id": "configurable",
    "weight": 1,
    "extension_attributes": {
        "stock_item": {
            "manage_stock": 1,
            "qty": "0.0000",
            "is_in_stock": true
        }
    },
    "options": [],
    "tier_prices": [],
    "media_gallery_entries": [{
        "media_type": "image",
        "label": "Levis Dawson Lace Up Boots - Dark Brown",
        "position": "0",
        "disabled": 0,
        "types": [],
        "file": "\/media\/catalog\/product\/i\/\/i\/m\/image_8637.jpg",
        "content": {
            "base64_encoded_data": "IMAGE BASE64 HERE",
            "type": "image\/jpeg",
            "name": "226787 705 29"
        }
    }, {
        "media_type": "image",
        "label": "Levis Dawson Lace Up Boots - Dark Brown",
        "position": "0",
        "disabled": 0,
        "types": [],
        "file": "\/media\/catalog\/product\/i\/\/i\/m\/image_8638.jpg",
        "content": {
            "base64_encoded_data": "IMAGE BASE64 HERE",
            "type": "image\/jpeg",
            "name": "226787 705 29"
        }
    }, {
        "media_type": "image",
        "label": "Levis Dawson Lace Up Boots - Dark Brown",
        "position": "0",
        "disabled": 0,
        "types": ["image", "small_image", "thumbnail", "swatch_image"],
        "file": "\/media\/catalog\/product\/i\/\/i\/m\/image_8639.jpg",
        "content": {
            "base64_encoded_data": "IMAGE BASE64 HERE",
            "type": "image\/jpeg",
            "name": "226787 705 29"
        }
    }],
    "attribute_set_id": 44,
    "custom_attributes": [{
        "attribute_code": "manufacturer",
        "value": "537"
    }, {
        "attribute_code": "color",
        "value": "453"
    }, {
        "attribute_code": "short_description",
        "value": "<span>Levis Dawson Lace Up Boots Dark Brown from Levi's are a great style option for your off-duty look. Featuring a soft leather outer, this pair has padded ankles for comfort and will team well with denim.<\/span><br><ul><li>Leather Comfort Insole<\/li><li>Anatomical Design<\/li><li>High Shock Absorption<\/li><li>Genuine Leather Coating<\/li><\/ul>"
    }, {
        "attribute_code": "barcode",
        "value": ""
    }, {
        "attribute_code": "category_ids",
        "value": [347]
    }, {
        "attribute_code": "meta_title",
        "value": "Levis Dawson Lace Up Boots - Dark Brown"
    }, {
        "attribute_code": "meta_keyword",
        "value": "levis,dawson,lace,up,boots,-,dark,brown,urbansurfer,urban,surfer,levi's,mens,shoes"
    }, {
        "attribute_code": "meta_description",
        "value": "Levis Dawson Lace Up Boots - Dark Brown - Shop online for a large range of  including Levi's with fast, free shipping from an official stockist."
    }, {
        "attribute_code": "news_from_date",
        "value": "2017-12-15 14:56:33"
    }, {
        "attribute_code": "news_to_date",
        "value": "2018-01-15 14:56:33"
    }]
},
"save_options": true
}
```

You can see that "types" is set the same for both calls but is just seemingly ignored for the Configurable Product, there is no trace of anything in the Magento 2 logs either.

This is consistently happening with every Configurable Product we have, yet all Single Products are working great. Child Products do not have any images set at all as intended. I've also tested adding a Configurable Product with no child products and the results are the same.

I can manually set the thumbnail, etc in the Magento 2 admin, but I need this to be automated via these REST calls. I've tried all sorts and just can't pin down what's going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

**Solution:**

I used catalogProductAttributeMediaGalleryManagementV1 to list all media gallery items (via GET ".../V1/products/TEST_SKU/media": list "id" and other fields).

After selecting the first image (with "media_type" = "image") I created a new JSON object.

```
{ 
    "entry":
    {
        "id": 1086,
        "media_type": "image",
        "label": "This is my image description",
        "position": 1,
        "disabled": false,
        "types": [ "image", "small_image", "thumbnail" ]
    }
}
```

After sending it using PUT (e.g. ".../V1/products/TEST_SKU/media/1086") the image saved correctly.

Comment: can't it be added in default product create api